# How to adjust the cumulative period and weigh in python code(effective drought index(EDI:BYUN, WILHITE 1999)

Tags: numpy, accumulate, weighting

I'm make a code, but big problem,, It takes too long to calculate.

In short, the definition of this EDI(Byun and wilhite 1999) 
EDI is accumulate and weighting precipitation index

pr = precipitation, accumulate days : 365 days(1 years) after accumulate days is redifined.

Big problem is redifined code..

my code is belows
Main code:  return_redifine_EP_MEP_DS

Sub code :  return_EP_v2, return_MEP_v2 , return_DEP_v2

Additional explanation

1. im using the python iris and numpy etc.,
2. EP_cube.data or MEP_cube.data . ".data" is arrays
3. Data sets. CMIP5 models precipitation(time, latitude, longitude)

origin_pr is precipitation and shape (time, latitude, longitude): 1971~2000

EP_cube   is accumulate precipitation and (time, latitude, longitude): 1972~2000

MEP_cube  is clim mean(each calendar day)of EP_cube(time, latitude, longitude):  365 days

DEP_cube  is EP_cube minus clim mean EP_cube(MEP) , (time, latitude, longitud): 1972~2000

sy,ey     is climatology years

day       is each models 1years day(example: HadGEM2-AO is 360days, ACCESS1-0: 365 days)

```
def return_redifine_EP_MEP_DS(origin_pr,EP_cube,DEP_cube,sy,ey,day):
    origin_DS = day
    origin_day= day
    DS_cube   = EP_cube - EP_cube.data + day
    DS        = origin_DS
    o_DEP_cube  =DEP_cube.copy()
    return_time = 0
    for j in range(0,DEP_cube.data.shape[1]):
        for k in range(0,DEP_cube.data.shape[2]):
           for i in range(1,DEP_cube.data.shape[0]):
             if DEP_cube.data[i,j,k] <0 and DEP_cube.data[i-1,j,k] < 0:
                DS = DS + 1
             else:
                DS =  origin_DS
             if DS != origin_DS:
                    EP_cube.data[i,j,k] = return_EP_v2(origin_pr[i-DS+origin_day:i+origin_day,j,k], DS)
                    day_of_year  = DEP_cube[i,j,k].coord('day_of_year').points
                    MEP_cube.data[day_of_year-1,j,k] = return_MEP_v2(EP_cube[:,j,k], sy, ey,day_of_year)
                    DEP_cube.data[i,j,k]             = return_DEP_v2(EP_cube[i,j,k], MEP_cube[day_of_year-1,j,k])
    return EP_cube, MEP_cube, DEP_cube, DS_cube
```

and sub code below

```
def return_EP_v2(origin_pr,DS):
    weights = np.arange(DS,0,-1)  ## 1/1, 1/2, 1/3 ....
    EP_data = np.sum(origin_pr.data / weights)
    return EP_data
def return_MEP_v2(EP_cube,sy,ey,day_of_year):
    ### Below mean is extract years and want days(julian day)
    ex_EP_cube = EP_cube.extract(iris.Constraint(year = lambda t: sy<=t<=ey, day_of_year = day_of_year ))
    ### Below mean is clim mean of EP_cube
    MEP_data = ex_EP_cube.collapsed('day_of_year',iris.analysis.MEAN).data
    return MEP_data
def return_DEP_v2(EP_cube, MEP_cube):
    DEP_data = EP_cube.data - MEP_cube.data
    return DEP_data
```

Comment: Shapes of all the relevant input arrays would be more helpful than what they represent.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of DS be reset to origin_DS after each iteration of the inner loop? Otherwise the value in the last timestep for one location will affect the calculation in the first timestep for the next location, which seems wrong.

Comment: yes, DS be reset to origin_DS after each iteration of the inner loop. and the code return redefined DS and MEP, EP, DEP,     first "I" days = 365 , if DEP negative(or possitive) consecutively for k days.  "i" changes to "i2" that is "(365 + k - 1).agarin with i2, EP, DEP MEP are calculated. "i2" return to 365 when EP365 from negative to postive(or from positive to negative  Only using data 1971.1.1-2000.12.31(365julian days).    if    1972.1.1 (DEP) = - 3, 1972.1.2(DEP) = -3.5 , 1972.1.3(DEP) = +1.5  then 1972.1.1(DS) = 365,  1972.1.2(DS) = 366, 1972.1.3(DS) = 365.